# Applying Script to all pages in project

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to remove mentioning scripts every page like

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

it should be mentioned at once.like a common place to refer for source.
i have my framework in 3.5. how can i achieve this.

Comment: You can use [MasterPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.ASPX)

Comment: What 3.5 ? What is the context ? Frame a question which is understandable .

Comment: @TheDarkKnight framework 3.5, OP is using ASP.net

Answer (score 1):

create a new project to hold all JavaScript files that you need want throughout the application. You can embed all the script into the DLL. That way, if the DLL is deployed to the website, all JavaScript files are also automatically deployed.

You can check out complete tutorial given below.

**[Managing-Your-JavaScript-Library-in-ASP-NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196727/Managing-Your-JavaScript-Library-in-ASP-NET)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using master page. Demo like

```
 <master page>
    <header>
    //add script file here
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   //Other scripts 
    </header>
    <content>
    <Sub pages>
    //Here you can debase your pages(like dynamically change pages), So the header script will referred from above header 
    </content>
    <footer>
    <//footer>
    <master page>
```

[MSDN link for Master page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.ASPX)

Comment: Adding a master page just to add reference of script ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a master page you could use a server control and add it to the pages as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a Master Page is good.

As an alternate way, you can achieve this by creating a base page and adding scripts from web.config file into the page's header by overriding Page class OnInit event.

Create a class as BasePage inheriting from System.Web.UI.Page like

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    }
```

On all the pages where you want to load the scripts, inherit them from BasePage

**Earlier**

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    }
```

**Now**

```
public partial class _Default : BasePage
    {
    }
```

Mention your script files at One place - **Web.Config** as below

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ScriptJquery" value="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"/>
    <add key="ScriptJqueryUI" value="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"/>
  </appSettings>
```

In the BasePage Class override OnInit as below

```
 public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) 
        { 
            IEnumerable<string> scripts =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Keys.OfType<string>().Where(s => s.StartsWith("Script"));
            foreach (string script in scripts)
            {
                Literal scriptTag = new Literal();
                scriptTag.Text = string.Format(@"<script src=""{0}"" type=""text/javascript""></script>",ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[script].ToString());
                Page.Header.Controls.Add(scriptTag);
            }

            base.OnInit(e); 
        }
    }
```